# sass math with multiple declaration

Tags: css, sass

So i have this little problem I want to avoid.

```
$var: 30px;

font: 25px/25px font,font,font;                   //Works
font: ($var - 5)/($var - 5) font, font, font;     //Works not
font: ($var - 5px)/($var - 5px) font, font, font; //Works not

margin: 0 0 20px 0;                               //Works
margin: 0 0 ($var - 10) 0;                        //Works not
margin: 0 0 ($var - 10px) 0;                      //Works not
```

Basically I have a width in a Variable that gets substracted multiple times. That it seems to be the problem is that it tries to divide both numbers with the slash.

I could use it like that:

```
margin-top: 0;
margin-right: 0;
margin-bottom: ($var - 10px);
margin-left: 0;
```

But this seems like a untidy method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this snippet on Sassmeister with SASS v.3.2.19

```
div {
  font: ($var - 5)#{"/"}($var - 5) font1, font2;     
  margin: 0 0 ($var - 10) 0; 
}
```

and the output is

```
div {
  font: 25px/25px  font1, font2;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
```

For the `font` I've escaped the `/` symbol, otherwise sass will try to execute a division

Answer (score 0):

Ok right after posting this, my colleague found the answer:

```
#{$var - 5}/#{$var - 5}
```

Comment: On sassmeister it seems it doesn't work. which version of sass are you using?

Comment: sass version 3.2.19 and compass version 0.12.7, as I said, probably an older version